# Showing another select when selected the first option

Tags: jquery, html, hide, html-select

I am trying to show a second select when I have selected an option in the first one. How can I do it using jQuery?

This is my code:

CSS:

```
#2nd{visibility: hidden;}    
#a{visibility: hidden;}
```

HTML:

```
pls select:
<select id='1st'>
      <option id='o1'>1</option>
      <option id='o2'>2</option>
      <option id='o3'>3</option>
      <option id='o4'>4</option>
</select>
</br>
<div id='a'>
<select id='2nd'>
      <option>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
</select></div>
```

What I want is when I select the first option the 1 it would show the second select but im having trouble showing it. I just know the basics but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: What happens if they select the 2nd option, or the 3rd or 4th?

Comment: sorry just updated it . it should just show another div or something T_T just trying to figure it out sorry just a beginner in jquery

Comment: Kindly check I edited my answer acc. to your requirement . You need to set the Visibility of that Div or Select to collapse onchange of Ist select .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change','#1st',function(){
    $('#'+$(this).val()+'nd').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#1st").change(function(){ 
     $("#2nd").css('visibility','collapse');
});
```

Hope this helps you.